# Get Redmine-Issues via REST API restricted by 'updated_by' grouped on 'updated_on'

Tags: rest, redmine, redmine-api

Considering [Redmine REST API](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) and http://theadmin.org/articles/redmine-query-reference I found no way to access the 'updated by/on' criteria of an issue.

So, is there any other possibiltiy to build a query that returns all issues that

- where updated by **me**
- group by **day_of(updated_on)**

**Update**

Actualy this SQL-Query on the Redmine-Database does what I want, but that is - obviously - no solid solution

```
select DATE(created_on), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT journalized_id ORDER BY journalized_id ASC SEPARATOR ',') 
from journals where user_id = <my user id> and journalized_type = 'Issue'
group by DATE(created_on) order by created_on desc;
```